# gawk FIELDWIDTHS convert to CSV, but convert cents to dollars for some fields

Tags: awk, currency-formatting

I am converting a transaction detail file received from the bank from fixed width into a CSV file.

```
 gawk '$1=$1' FIELDWIDTHS='1 8 12 23 6 6 6 7 13 9 3 10 1 2 3 1 3 1 1 2 6 3 12 3 3 1 2 9 19 140  ' OFS=, $f  >> $csvfilename
```

Some of the fields are currency fields and listed in cents.
For example, the second last field will have a value "1234567".
However, the value I want output is  "12345.67".

I am looking for how I can do that conversion. Something like

```
FIELDWIDTHS='1 8 12 23 6 6 6 7.2 13 '
```

As an example. the following input is received

> 1000000000000027302080000000541282******876421111821111821111800648300000000021687000000000PU
> 831712     DR90 020N000000000323132106663755
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

The resulting CSV file is

> 1,00000000,000002730208,0000000448387******6098,211115,211116,211116,0120456,0000000051580,000000000,PU
> ,754045    , ,DR,90 ,0,20N,0,0,00,000003,211,31912995587 ,   ,
> 0,0,00,000000000,0000000000000000000,0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

The 8th field has a value "0120456".
I would like the value in the resulting comma delimited file to read "01204.56"

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please post samples of input and expected output in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: Fair enough @Cyrus and ravinderSingh13. I have duly updated my question with more information regarding the input and expected output.

Comment: Thanks for adding samples, sorry but looks like its still not clear. Could you please do mention Logic of getting output that will make question more clear IMHO, cheers.

Comment: If I run your `gawk` command on your sample output, I get `1,00000000,000002730208,0000000541282******8764,211118,211118,211118,0064830,0000000021687`.  Not what you put as the resulting CSV...  So in this  you would want to have `0064830` split to `00648.30` ?

Comment: @Nic3500 there are a few extra fields I ommited from the actual FIELDWIDTHS value. I have now added the complete one But yes in principle I want one of the fields 0064830 to be 00648.30 in the CSV

Comment: I'm not sure why someone will want to close this query. If you can't answer someone else might. I supplied background, I supplied sample data. I supplied my command. Thanks to those who took the time to engage

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 what clarity do you need. I supplied the fixed width file and the gawk command. I supplied the sample output and explained that some of the fields are displayed as cents (eg 0120456) but should be currency format (eg 01204.56)

Comment: @crafter, I was not clear on logic so I asked, may be others could help on this one. FYI please I haven't downvoted or close voted this.

Comment: Your input contains no `0120456`.

Comment: @crafter: for clarity, your samples should fit your code, see minimal reproducible example. People looking at your question will wonder how you got the output you desire, with the input you posted. Selecting fields will never result in that.

Comment: Thanks @Nic3500, but it does. If you place the input into a file and run the gawk command it gets the output. The input and output is one line - it appears as many due to the formatting on SO.

Comment: @crafter it's not "the formatting on SO" that's the problem, it's the specific formatting constructs you chose to use. Format your sample input, output, and code with code delimiters (3 ticks either side or lines indented by 4 blanks), not whatever it is that prefixing lines with `>` is intended for. You're also supposed to provide a [mcve] (note **minimal**) - we don't need to see input that wraps lines and apparently has 30+ fields just for you to demonstrate whatever your specific problem is you're asking for help with. Just create and show us lines of, say, 10 chars with 3 fields each.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton Point taken. I did exactly that - provided minimal reproducible sample, 1 line input; 1 output and corresponding gawk command and was asked for more, which I then provided. Now I am being asked for less. Perhaps my main mistake was using the quotes for the data rather than the tick characters, which I explained. Still, I suppose questions have wide audiences who requires different things to enable them to assist. I don't take the downvotes personally. I will however fight to not close this issue.  I am grateful for those that engaged and I'm testing out the suggestions now.

Comment: Yeah, 1 line of input/output is always inadequate if your real data contains 2 or more lines. There's more to providing an example than "more" or "less" - you're just being asked to create and post a [mcve] and format your sample input/output as required for it to not be ambiguous regarding where any newlines occur, just like everyone else posting a question here (see [ask]). Look at other questions that have been upvoted and answered if you're not sure how to format yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that I think you can use, or adapt.

## Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

line="1000000000000027302080000000541282******876421111821111821111800648300000000021687000000000PU 831712     DR90 020N000000000323132106663755 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

echo "$line" | awk -f so.awk
```

## so.awk

```
BEGIN {
    FIELDWIDTHS = "1 8 12 23 6 6 6 7 13 9 3 10 1 2 3 1 3 1 1 2 6 3 12 3 3 1 2 9 19 140"
}

{
    # Print first 7 fields
    for (i=1; i<=7; i++) {
        printf "%s,", $i
    }

    # Print 8th field
    firstXchars = substr($8, 0, length($8)-2)
    lasttwochars = substr($8, length($8)-1)
    printf "%s.%s,", firstXchars, lasttwochars

    # Print the rest of fields, except the last one (I do not want the , for the last one)
    for (j=9; j<=NF-1; j++) {
        printf "%s,", $j
    }

    # Print the last field
    print $NF
}
```

## What it does

- print the first 7 fields separated by `,` , no changes
- for the 8th field, extract the characters *except* the last two
- for the 8th field, extract the last two characters
- print field 8 with `(except last two).(last two),`
- print all remaining fields but the last one separated by `,`
- print the last field

## Output

```
$ ./so.bash 
1,00000000,000002730208,0000000541282******8764,211118,211118,211118,00648.30,0000000021687,000000000,PU ,831712    , ,DR,90 ,0,20N,0,0,00,000003,231,32106663755 ,000,000,0,00,000000000,0000000000000000000,000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^
```

**Note** `^^^^^^^^` is not part of the output, I just highlight field 8

With the method highlighted here for managing field 8, you can adapt the script to fit your actual data and output requirements.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat file
foo12345bar

$ awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='3 5 3' -v OFS=',' '{sub(/..$/,".&",$2)} 1' file
foo,123.45,bar
```